# Application of a recursive function within a dplyr context in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I do use dplyr for almost (if not all) my data handling but I always struggle with one thing in R: recursive calculations.

Context: I have a sorted data frame storing items with `ID` (thus a "group" notion) with some `VALUES`. Some of them are missing but can be calculated iteratively using a coefficient `COEFF`. I am looking for a simple and elegant way to do that (without a loop). Any clues?

Note: We assume that there is always a first non NA value for each `ID`.

Below a reproductible example with expected solution:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = rep(letters[1:2], each = 5),
                 VALUE = c(1, 3, NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, 3, NA, NA),
                 COEFF = c(1, 2, 1, .5, 100, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
)

df_full <- df
# SOLUTION 1: Loop
for(i in 1:nrow(df_full))
{
  if(is.na(df_full$VALUE[i])){
    df_full$VALUE[i] <- df_full$VALUE[i-1]*df_full$COEFF[i]
  }
}
df_full
#   ID VALUE COEFF
#1   a   1.0   1.0
#2   a   3.0   2.0
#3   a   3.0   1.0
#4   a   1.5   0.5
#5   a 150.0 100.0
#6   b   2.0   1.0
#7   b   2.0   1.0
#8   b   3.0   1.0
#9   b   3.0   1.0
#10  b   3.0   1.0

# PSEUDO-SOLUTION 2: using Reduce()
# I struggle to apply this approach for each "ID", like we could do in dplyr using dplyr::group_by()
# Exemple for the first ID:
Reduce(function(v, x) x*v, x = df$COEFF[3:5], init = df$VALUE[2], accumulate = TRUE)

# PSEUDO-SOLUTION 3: dplyr::lag()
# We could think that we just have to use the lag() function to get the previous value, like such:
df %>% 
  mutate(VALUE = ifelse(is.na(VALUE), lag(VALUE) * COEFF, VALUE))
# but lag() is not "refreshed" after each calculation, it basically takes a copy of the VALUE column at the begining and adjust indexes.
```

Comment: Maybe it's better to start your `for`-loop at `2` like `2:nrow(df_full)` instead of `1:nrow(df_full)` as it refers to `df_full$VALUE[i-1]`

Comment: perhaps have a look at the data.table [way for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41891693/13513328)

Comment: With `Reduce` the flowing might work: `unlist(Reduce(function(v, x) {if(is.na(x["VALUE"])) v["VALUE"] * x["COEFF"] else x["VALUE"]}, x = asplit(df[-1, 2:3], 1), init = df[1, 2, drop=FALSE], accumulate = TRUE))`. I think there is no need for *ID* as you said you start every time with a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can probably get what you need here with a mix of `tidyr::fill` to fill `NA` values from above, combined with `cumprod` to get the cumulative effect of multiplying by the coefficient, and `ifelse` to choose when to use it. There's also a "working" column named V which is created and destroyed in the process.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(V = tidyr::fill(df, VALUE)$VALUE) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(VALUE = ifelse(is.na(VALUE), 
                        V * cumprod(ifelse(is.na(VALUE), COEFF, 1)), 
                        VALUE)) %>% select(-V)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>    ID    VALUE COEFF
#>    <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 a       1     1  
#>  2 a       3     2  
#>  3 a       3     1  
#>  4 a       1.5   0.5
#>  5 a     150   100  
#>  6 b       2     1  
#>  7 b       2     1  
#>  8 b       3     1  
#>  9 b       3     1  
#> 10 b       3     1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Allan, indeed that's the spirit I was expecting. For information if you add `%>% ungroup()` we indeed have `identical()` TRUE between the dplyr solution and the loop solution. Dplyr solution is ~7 times faster than the loop.

Answer (score 4):

A fully recursive way :

```
calc <- function(val,coef){
  for(i in 2:length(val))
  {
    if(is.na(val[i])){
      val[i] <- val[i-1]*coef[i]
    }
  }
  return(val)
}

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(newval = calc(VALUE, COEFF))

  ID    VALUE COEFF newval
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 a         1   1      1  
 2 a         3   2      3  
 3 a        NA   1      3  
 4 a        NA   0.5    1.5
 5 a        NA 100    150  
 6 b         2   1      2  
 7 b         2   1      2  
 8 b         3   1      3  
 9 b        NA   1      3  
10 b        NA   1      3
```

`group_by` provides to `mutate` a subset of the original data fields for each ID.

You can then process these vectors in a standard recursive loop and give back a result vector of equal length to the `mutate` statement to put the results together.

If you need speed, the for-loop can easily be accelerated with `Rcpp` :

```
library(Rcpp)
Rcpp::cppFunction('
NumericVector calc(NumericVector val, NumericVector coef) {
  int n = val.size();
  int i;
  for (i = 1;i<n;i++){
      if(R_IsNA(val[i])){
        val[i] = val[i-1]*coef[i];
      }
    }
return val;
}')
```

Comment: The OP was hoping for a method without loops, but writing the looping function in Rcpp is a good solution here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Waldi. I was indeed hoping to avoid loops, even in Rcpp.